# Best way to authenticate client side JavaScript events

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, authentication, http-post

So I have a JavaScript and php web app. In my app I have times where JavaScript will call a POST request that creates a post for example. I want to know what is the best way to authenticate my request to prevent anybody from just going to that URL. It doesn't need to be that flexible. I'm not going to have multiple apps. I just need a one case solution in php and JavaScript.

**EDIT**: second question. Is just making sure the URL the request is coming from enough?

Comment: may be should try looking at serverside javascript like node.js.

Comment: @DipeshParmar — Since the data has to come from the user, that isn't practical. (Unless the OP wants all the content on the site to be written by Markov text generators instead of humans).

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

You can do things like adding an extra header to the request when it comes from your JavaScript, but since you have to send the instructions on how to do that to the browser, anyone can read them and duplicate them for their custom built non-JS request.

On the WWW you can authenticate people (with credentials), but you can't authenticate clients (unless you supply the client software in a compiled bundle … and even that isn't reliable, the official Twitter client auth keys are out in the wild now).

> Is just making sure the URL the request is coming from enough?

If you mean "checking the referer header", then no. That is set by the client, and the client can set it to whatever they like.

Answer (score 1):

Best thing would probably be to establish a PHP session and send an identification stored in $_SESSION to the javascript. In every AJAX POST you add this identification and check it serverside to what is stored in $_SESSION. If they do not match it's either someone trying to manipulate the URL or a CSRF.

If you want to prevent the original client from doing multiple requests within a session you will need to send a nounce-number from the server to the client which will be usuable only once. See:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce

Comment: All that data is still sent to the client though, so it can be used for whatever purposes the client wants.

Comment: Using nounce they can at least only do it once. They have to "request" the permission to send a POST to the server. That way you can control what the client is allowed to do and simply ignore request without a proper nounce.

Comment: And while requesting permission is another step, that is all it is. It can be automated as easily as anything else.

Answer (score 0):

You can place this line on top of your script

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('Permission denied: direct access');
```

as the first line of your php file you are sending the POST to.

**EDIT** -> Or something like

```
 if(!isset($_POST))
   {
      die('no direct access allowed');
   }
   else
   {

     //all your PHP code

    }
```

you could also include your own variable in the post and use it in

> isset($_POST['your variable'])

to check.

Comment: The goal is to stop people access the page if they don't request it with JS, not to make it accessible only if `include()`ed in another page.

Comment: yes, Thank you Quentin. I guess the EDIT in the answer  should serve the purpose.